# What is the default value for @Consumes in REST web service?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

In REST web service, if @Consumes is not specified for web service which is @POST and also there is no class level @Consumes then does it mean the web service accepts any MIME media type or is there any default value for @Consumes ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `@Consumes` defines the media types that the methods of a resource
>   class or `MessageBodyReader` can accept. If not specified, a container
>   will assume that any media type is acceptable.

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html)

Look [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipzh/index.html#6nmq2cp2i) for the detailed description